# How do I install pthreads on Debian?

Tags: php, pthreads

Suprisingly, I can't find this anywhere. I'm trying to use the `php` Thread class. To do this I have to install `pthreads`.

How do I install `pthreads` on `Debian 8`?

Comment: try these https://gist.github.com/wazdev/b1c501f54e282efcda33

Answer (score 3):

Pthreads is part of the libc6 package:

```
dpkg -L libc6 | grep pthread
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
```

You might need need libc6-dev if you are compiling stuff:

```
dpkg -L libc6-dev | grep pthread
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/pthreadtypes.h
/usr/include/pthread.h
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.a
```